# Is this valid argument? Inverse matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I just wanted to know if my argument below is valid, since the solution from the book shows a different solution.

Let $A = $ $ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 3 \\
0 & 2 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}  $ and $C = $ $ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 2 & 3 
\end{bmatrix}  $

Determine if there exists a matrix $B$ such that $ABC = A$.

My solution is the following:

If there would exist a matrix $B$ like that, it would be the left-inverse to $C$, but since $C$ is neither surjective or injective, inverse does not exist. Therefore, there does not exist such matrix $B$.

Is there anything im missing out on here?

Thanks!

Comment: you are assuming without any justification that B would have to be left-inverse to C.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is what I was worried about. How would I justify this? Is there any way $ABC=A$ can be true? The reason im thinking this is that $BC$ would have to be equal to $I$, which makes $ABC=A$

Comment: Consider the rank.

Comment: If $A$ were not the $A$ in the question but a really stupid $A$, like the one consisting of all zeroes then there would be many solutions where $BC \neq I$. So *some* argument is needed...

Comment: Use the fact that $\text{rank}(XY)\le \min(\text{rank}(X),\text{rank}(Y))$.

Comment: @durianice Do you mean rank(X) multiplied by rank(Y) on the right hand side?

Comment: @zzz__ No. The right hand side is the minimum of $\text{rank}(X)$ and $\text{rank}(Y)$. The inequality is equivalent to two inequalities: $\text{rank}(XY)\le \text{rank}(X)$ and $\text{rank}(XY)\le \text{rank}(Y)$.